# Exception: class cannot be cast to android.app.activity

Tags: android

I want to extend another class not Activity in my android app. But when I run the application after initializing it in manifest file it shows the exception `class cannot be cast to android.app.activity` how can I solve this problem?
Edited : 
This is my class file SessionLoginSampleActivity.java which calls FacebookSignIn

```
 public class SessionLoginSampleActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }        }
        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }
    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(SessionLoginSampleActivity.this, FacebookSignIn.class), 100);
            }
        else{
            onClickLogin();      }    }

   private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }    }

    private void onClickLogout() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateView();
        }    } }
```

FacebookSignIn.java

```
    public class FacebookSignIn extends FacebookFragment{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     fetchUserInfo();
     if(databaseExists()!=false)
     {
            if(!checkValidUser()!=true){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),UserAccount.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                /*Sending some arguments*/ 
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                  bundle.putString("UserName",strUserName);
                  bundle.putString("Id", strEmailId);
                  intent.putExtras(bundle);
                this.startActivity(intent);
        }}}
private boolean databaseExists(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;     
    try {       
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        if(checkDB != null){
            System.out.println("DataBase Exists");
            checkDB.close(); 
            return true;
        }else{  
            //database does not exist  
            return false;
        }     
    } catch (Exception e){
        //database does not exist        
        return false;   
    }}  

private Boolean checkValidUser(){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try{
        cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT loginId, emailAddress FROM UserDetails WHERE loginId = '"+NAME+"' AND emailAddress = '"+ID+"'", null);
        if (cursor != null ) {
            if  (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                strUserName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("loginId"));
                strEmailId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("emailAddress"));
                        }}          
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    }finally {
      if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) cursor.close();
    }
    return true;
}    
private void fetchUserInfo() {
    final Session currentSession = getSession();
    if (currentSession != null && currentSession.isOpened()) {
        if (currentSession != userInfoSession) {
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(currentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser me, Response response) {
                    if (currentSession == getSession()) {
                        user = me;                           
                        updateUI();
                    }
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        //loginButton.handleError(response.getError().getException());
                    }}});
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString(FIELDS, REQUEST_FIELDS);
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
            userInfoSession = currentSession;
        }
    } else {
        user = null;
    }}

private void updateUI() {
    if (!isAdded()) {
        return;
    }
    if (isSessionOpen()) {
       // connectedStateLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_connected_text_color));
       // connectedStateLabel.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, -1f,
              //  getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_connected_shadow_color));

        if (user != null) {
            ImageRequest request = getImageRequest();
            if (request != null) {
                URI requestUrl = request.getImageUri();
                // Do we already have the right picture? If so, leave it alone.
                //if (!requestUrl.equals(connectedStateLabel.getTag())) {
                    if (user.getId().equals(userProfilePicID)) {

                    } else {
                        ImageDownloader.downloadAsync(request);
                    }}}}} 

private ImageRequest getImageRequest() {
    ImageRequest request = null;
    try {
        ImageRequest.Builder requestBuilder = new ImageRequest.Builder(
                getActivity(),
                ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUrl(
                        user.getId(),
                        getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_profile_picture_width),
                        getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_profile_picture_height)));

        request = requestBuilder.setCallerTag(this)
                .setCallback(
                        new ImageRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(ImageResponse response) {
                                processImageResponse(user.getId(), response);
                            }})
                .build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    }
    return request;
}

private void processImageResponse(String id, ImageResponse response) {
    if (response != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = response.getBitmap();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(FacebookSignIn.this.getResources(), bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0,
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_profile_picture_width),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_profile_picture_height));
            userProfilePic = drawable;
            userProfilePicID = id;

        } } }}
```

Comment: You are using your class as an activity. but it isn't. If you don't show us code it is impossible to say _where_ you are going wrong, but basically it should be obvious that if you use something just the way you would use an activity, then it might just need to be one (or be one of its childs)

Comment: Are you sure "UserAccount" is your Activity??? And you are not trying to add FacebookSignIn  to your manifest file.

Comment: No, exception raised When I call FacebookSignIn in SessionLoginSampleActivity

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare classes other than Activity in Android Manifest.

Only add classes which extend Activity. Like FragmentActivity,Activity and so on.

Hope this helps

Comment: But when I compile, it shows exception `have you declared this activity in AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely `UserAccount` you're trying to start as an activity, is in fact not an `Activity`.

Activities should extend `android.app.Activity` either directly or indirectly via some intermediate subclass.